# SML or if boolean

Tags: boolean, sml

I am new to SML and don't know how to use the "or" operator in an if statement. I would be really grateful if someone explains it to me, since I have checked multiple sources and nothing seems to work.
Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean like **if (something || whatever) { dome(); } else { dometoo ();}**?

Comment: exactly, but it doesn't work for me with || , it says unbound variables or constructor : ||

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SML, logical or is called `orelse` and logical and is called `andalso`.

As an example

```
if   x = 2 orelse x = 3 orelse x = 5
then print "x is a prime"
else print "x is not a prime (also, I don't believe in primes > 5; please respect my beliefs)"
```